# Meteor - How to send notification to user on android?

Tags: android, ios, mongodb, cordova, meteor

I'm very new in meteor and I just made a simple app that show news (text) for a school, the problem is that no one knows when they write something new because the app doesn't have notification. I can't figure out how to use raix:push or richsilv:cordova-notifications because the test of raix:push didn't work in my device (android) and richsilv:cordova-notifications just work with android and I couldn't make it automatic. Saying "automatic" I mean "when the mongo collection is updated a notification is sent"

Comment: if you want to display the push message only when the app is available, you can try collection hooks on client-side (like afterUpdate).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to set up push server for sending notification to Android client.

Google is providing such option, where client app has to register with GCM server. On successful registration, google will give reg Id, which has to be stored in DB.

From your server make HTTP request to GCM server with Reg Id and message. GCM will deliver the message to appropriate device.

Please refer https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm